# How to make a route from an array

Tags: arrays, sorting, routes, tuples

I would like to create a route In Python from the following data
([[ 0,  1],[ 0,  2],[ 0,  8],[ 1,  7],[ 2,  9],[ 3,  6],[ 4,  3],[ 5,  0],[ 6,  0], [ 7,  0][ 8,  4],[ 9,  5],[10, 10]])

The outcome that I would like to have would be a route like [0,1][1,7],[7,0] (0-1-7-0) and [0,2],[2,9][9,5][5,0] (0-2-9-5-0) and [0,8][8,4][4,3][3,6][6,0] (0-8-4-3-6-0). I have tried making the first array into a tuple and I think that would work, but can't seem to find how to sort the array.

Is there some kind of loop which could help me sort it and thereafter make tuples of it?

Answer (score 0):

The "data" that you have describes a **graph**. I suggest adding this keyword to your question.

The **vertices** of the graph are the integers `0` to `10`. The **edges** of the graph are your 2-element lists `[0, 1]`, `[0, 2]`, `[0, 8]`, etc.

Now you are looking for a **path** through your graph. What requirements do you have on the path you're looking for? Should it be the **longest path** in the graph? Should it be the **shortest path** between two particular nodes?

If you're only looking for a **maximal path**, i.e. a path that cannot be further extended, then a greedy algorithm suffices:

```
initialize the path with one arbitrary edge
loop:
  look for an edge in data that can extend the path
  pop the edge from data and add it to the path
  break the loop when no appropriate edge can be found in data
```

Comment: It is true that the data comes from a graph. The graph is from a small TSP that I have made an outcome gives these nice loops in the graph. But the output is not a route but just gives the linepeaces in my route. These are then plotted and make a whole loop, but the route itself is not yet shown and I would like to show it. So that is why I would like to above stated manner.